# How to convert php array into javascript array for Highchart JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I have a php array created according to the format I wish to insert into a javascript array variable. My php array values are currently :

```
Array ( [0] => "Butter noob", 26375 [1] => "Crab Vermecilli", 0 [2] => "Salted Egg Yolk Crab", 0 )
```

Now , i need this array to replace the values within the javascript function code snippet below :

```
series: [{
    name: 'Delivered amount',
    data: [
        ['Bananas', 8],
        ['Kiwi', 3],
        ['Mixed nuts', 1],
        ['Oranges', 6],
        ['Apples', 8],
        ['Pears', 4],
        ["Clementines", 4],
        ['Reddish (bag)', 1],
        ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
    ]
}]
```

So after including my converted php array into the javascript function, it should look something like :

```
series: [{
    name: 'Delivered amount',
    data: [
        ["Butter Noob", 26375],
        ["Crab Vermecelli", 0],
        ["Salted Egg Yolk Crab", 0],

    ]
}]
```

Can anyone assist me on this matter? I tried json_encode but im stucked now. How do i use converted php array with json_encode under such situation ?

Answer (score 2):

use JsonEncode

in `.php` file

```
  <?php $data=Array ( [0] => "Butter noob", 26375 [1] => "Crab Vermecilli", 0 [2] => "Salted Egg Yolk Crab", 0 ) ;?>
<script>
        series: [{
            name: 'Delivered amount',
            data: JSON.parse(<?php echo(json_encode($data));?>);
        }]
</script>
```

Comment: there is an error : missing } after property list
[Break On This Error] data: JSON.parse(["\"Butter noob\",..., 0","\"Salted Egg Yolk Crab\", 0"]);

Comment: define the $data as  $data=Array ( [0] => Array("Butter noob", 26375), 
                [1] => Array("Crab Vermecilli", 0),
                [2] => Array("Salted Egg Yolk Crab", 0) ) ;

Comment: the valeus are converted to json but the error is still persisting. Im seeing in Firebug the following code : series: [{
name: 'Delivered amount',
data: JSON.parse(["\"Butter noob\", 26375","\"Crab Vermecilli\", 0","\"Salted Egg Yolk Crab\", 0"]);
}]

Comment: i copied paste ur code and the following error came out Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Finalv2\graph.php on line 78

Answer (score 1):

*IN PHP file:*

```
$data = json_encode(array(
  array("Butter noob", 26375), 
  array("Crab Vermecilli", 0), 
  array('Salted Egg Yolk Crab', 0)
));

<script>
var series = [{
    name: 'Delivered amount',
    data: JSON.parse( <?php echo $data ?> )
}];
</script>

... chart 
series: series
```

Answer (score 0):

in the php use: echo json_encode(yourarray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); Then in javascript use

```
$.getJSON('urltoyourphp', function(data){
     var series = [{
         name: 'Delivered amount',
         data: data
     }];
});
```